# Spring Integration Flow - how to call a service and receive response on separate channel

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to build a Spring Integration Flow with DSL where a part of the flow calls an existing service that will process data asynchronously and return the response on a channel. The service call returns a task ID that can be used as a correlation ID to obtain the correct response message on the channel.

I am unsure how to build a flow (which components to use) that will call the service (I assume with a service activator), then take the returned ID and then wait for a message on a different channel that has that ID in the correlation ID header (maybe some sort of aggregator?). I have googled and cannot find anything that seems similar.

Also, my flow will receive a request object that I would like to pair up with the response object to pass along the flow after the response is received.

```
Request -> service call -> returns task ID ---->|
                |                               |---- (Request+Response) --> More processing
                | (async)                       |
                ---------> Response ----------->|
                           for task ID 
                           on task complete channel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The best way to solve your task is really an aggregator pattern:

https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/Aggregator.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#aggregator

So, you probably need to use a header enricher to instead of a service activator to obtain that `task ID` in the reply and store it in a header for future correlation of this request and some reply later with the same `task ID`. Or if you have a property on the request object for this `task ID`, you can use a content enricher instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-transformation.html#content-enricher

Then you send this request object with the `task ID` to an aggregator where this `task ID` must be used as a correlation key. The group size of course is just `2` - request and reply.

Your async service must send a completion to the same aggregator's input channel with. When aggregator encounters a proper correlation key, it will complete the group of two messages and send a single one to its output channel.

**UPDATE**

The aggregator we are talking about must have its own input channel, so you can send a request with `task ID` for correlation and then from your async service a reply must be sent to the same channel. With Java DSL it is a matter of exposing that input channel for your convenience:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow aggregatorFlow() {
    return f -> f
              .aggregate(...)
              .channel("correlatedReplyChannel")
}
```

This flow implicitly starts with a channel like `aggregatorFlow.input`. So, you use this name in a `channel()` definition of request and reply flows as the last EIP-method in their definitions.

Comment: Thanks, that has given me a different perspective to look at it from. How do I configure the aggregator input channel in a DSL Integration Flow?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Ok, so I need to break things down into several small flow definitions rather than a larger flow definition. Is that the recommended way of working with Integration Flows? Also, I was trying to create my flow definitions in classes inheriting from IntegrationFlowAdapter, but it seems it is not possible to create the above aggregatorFlow that way as it seems I have to start with a "from" method?

Comment: Well, the `IntegrationFlowAdapter` is good for a linear flow. In your case you have to branches: one sends request to the aggregator and forgets; another waits for reply and send it to the same aggregator. So, it is definitely look like individual flows. You can have several `IntegrationFlow` `@Bean`s encapsulated into one `@Configuration` class. You can do that with a single flow though: just have a `channel()` in between your service call and an `aggregator()`. It doesn't matter where you declare channel, you always can send a message to it from the outside, like your async service reply.